# Save file to a specific folder in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am trying to save some selected file in a folder(images) inside my application
[image]

I am able to get the file using following code:

```
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string imagelocation = "";

        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if(dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
        {
            textBox2.Text = dialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```

For saving the file I got in textBox2, I tried following code. But with following code I have to also select the path where I want to save the file.
What If I want to (set my path permanently to 'images' folder as shown in pic) for saving?

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SaveFileDialog f = new SaveFileDialog();

        if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using(Stream s = File.Open(f.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
            using(StreamWriter sw =  new StreamWriter(s))
            {
                sw.Write(textBox2.Text);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Have you seen the properties of the [FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog) class? Or inspected the properties of the SafeFileDialog derived class? See [InitialDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory) and [RestoreDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory), for example.

Comment: I'm guessing you want [`System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).

Comment: Hi Shashwath, does it solve your problem or is there anything else I can improve to meet your requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 2 Approaches to Solve this problem

- **First Approach:** ***(Browser the File and click  Save, to automatically save the selected file to Image Directory)***

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        var assemblyPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var assemblyParentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
        var imageDir = Path.Combine(assemblyParentPath, "Image");

        if (!Directory.Exists(imageDir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(imageDir);


         using (Stream s = File.Open(imageDir+"\\"+Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text), FileMode.CreateNew))
         using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
         {
                     sw.Write(textBox1.Text);
         }

     }
```

---

- **Second Approach: (Browser the File and Save Opens SaveDialog with Directory as Image Directory and File name as Previously selected File)**

````
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            var assemblyPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var assemblyParentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
            var imageDir = Path.Combine(assemblyParentPath, "Image");

            if (!Directory.Exists(imageDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imageDir);

            SaveFileDialog f = new SaveFileDialog();
            f.InitialDirectory = imageDir;
            f.FileName = textBox1.Text;
            if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream s = File.Open(imageDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text), FileMode.CreateNew))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                {
                    sw.Write(textBox1.Text);
                }

            }
        }```
````

Comment: Why not set the `RestoreDirectory` property or set `InitialDirectory` to the path previously opened with `OpenFileDialog`? `SaveFileDialog` is gone, maybe the OP needed it, since it was there before... Apparently, the OP just wanted the Save dialog to open already set to the same path selected with the Open dialog.

Comment: Do not manually concatenate paths. Please use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`, which is much safer and bug free.

Comment: Hi Shashwath, does it solve your problem or is there anything else you're looking for ?

Comment: @Jimi, Updated the solution with another approach using `InitialDirectory` now `SaveDialog` opens with specific `Directory` and specific `File`

Comment: @ja72, I had used `Path.Combine` for `ImageDir` and only in `File.Open` , `\\`  was used, which I believe should be fine under the circumstances

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work for you?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Title = "Select Picture";
    dlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
    dlg.Filter = "Common Picture Files|*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;|All Files|*.*";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dlg.FileName;
    }
}
```